How to model a tooth
I'm a beginner in blender.
I can only make simple objects like desks through YouTube tutorials so far.
Do you have any tips for creating a tooth (such as in the attached images)?


The dents on the top or the four legs seem to me to be hard to make.
Is there a modifier I can use to make it?

A big help here would be the Subdivision Surface modifier. It's great for making blobby shapes out of a "low-poly" base mesh.

Do you know about the Blender manual?
